# Do we need both FD_SOCK and FD_ALL in JGroups UDP Configuration?

Tags: java, cluster-computing, jgroups

We're looking at using JGroups and in trying to evaluate which configuration makes sense for our purposes, I notice that the standard udp.xml configuration (and its variations) have both FD_SOCK and FD_ALL specified.  Are both really needed for a standard UDP-based cluster messaging configuration?

I would suspect that FD_SOCK gives you more immediate failure detection, but is that the only benefit?  And assuming so, why would you want/need FD_ALL?  (Is it that FD_SOCK will only let you know if your neighbor node is dead, but FD_ALL is for the whole cluster?)

Basically I'm just trying to understand the pros/cons of each to see if it makes sense to remove one of the protocols to keep things as simple as possible.

Thanks in advance!
Scott

Answer (score 2):

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/FDVersusFDSOCK. Replace FD with FD_ALL, as this is the same onceptually

Comment: Appreciate the info, but this does not quite answer my question.  My question is whether both FD_ALL and FD_SOCK are really needed together.  JGroups is delivered with a set of template configurations, one of them udp.xml, which has both FD_ALL and FD_SOCK.  I'm guessing both are useful, and that FD_SOCK gives you a more immediate indication of a dead node, but FD_ALL is a way to get cluster-wide heartbeats?  If I wanted to reduce multicast traffic, would FD_SOCK be sufficient, or would that only let nodes know neighbors go away only?

Comment: There are situations which FD_SOCK cannot detect (soon), as the link states them. Therefore, yes, both are useful. The question whether these are needed depends on your application - I can't tell you whether you need e.g. the UNICASTx protocol as I don't know whether you need to deliver messages ordered and reliably. With FDx, it's similar.

Answer (score 2):

You could use FD_SOCK only, but then you would detect crashed members only, but not hanging member (which don't close the TCP connection), crashed switches or pulled plugs. That's why the default config includes both protocols.