# JGroups : difference between FD_SOCK, FD_ALL and VERIFY_SUSPECT. Any disadvantage to using all 3?

Tags: jgroups

Based on the documentation, these are the definition given to each 3 (FD_SOCK_, FD_ALL, VERIFY_SUSPECT).

[image]

Their behavior seems to overlap each other, yet do things slightly different.

[image]

The one missing topic within the documentation is WHEN to specifically use each one, a combination of more than one or all three together.

This post was found : [Do we need both FD_SOCK and FD_ALL in JGroups UDP Configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382016/do-we-need-both-fd-sock-and-fd-all-in-jgroups-udp-configuration) which provided a nice answer at the bottom and is a start to answering this question but does fall a bit short.

Are there any notes or feedback related to WHEN specifically use each one, a combination of more than one or all three together?